# Add loading to html table using reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox, redux

I'm doing something like a friends list and send request.
In my project, I am supposed to allow add multiple connections together.
So I have table in html and multiple check-boxes. I want, after selecting some check box, for it to send a request.

I will post the request for each one and in the meantime when it's successful, I want to additionally show "Td Done" or "Successfully sent".
So I'm trying to select the row to add the successful message but I couldn't.

In this link I'm showing the basic screen.

https://repl.it/@ZaherZaki/SubduedProudMath

Comment: I would suggest, you make each row entry as a component and the component can be responsible for adding the `Successful` message to its own entry when the query is complete.

Comment: Thanks alot for ur reply, please do u have any example?

Comment: i dont think it's applicable  as i will send the multiple requests together.

Comment: For this case you may need JQuery or VanillaJS.

Comment: There are many ways. For starter, take a look on `promises`, how to use them with api, also take look at `axios` or similar promise based libraries if you are waiting for an api. If you use redux you'll be able to use the actions and states to do this

Comment: Okay, here is the [repl](https://repl.it/repls/PrevailingActiveCommas)

Comment: You've tagged redux, but are you actually using redux in your app?